# Using File Extension Wildcards in os.listdir(path)

Tags: python

I have a directory of files that I am trying to parse using Python. I wouldn't have a problem if they were all the same extension, but for whatever reason they are created with sequential numeric extensions after their original extension. For example: `foo.log foo.log.1 foo.log.2 bar.log bar.log.1 bar.log.2 etc.` On top of that, foo.log is in XML format, while bar.log is not. What's the best route to take in order to read and parse only the `foo.log.*` *and* `foo.log` files? The `bar.log` files do not need to be read. Below is my code:

```
import os
from lxml import etree
path = 'C:/foo/bar//'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for files in listing:
    if files.endswith('.log'):
        print files
        data = open(os.path.join(path, files), 'rb').read()
        tree = etree.fromstring(data)
        search = tree.findall('.//QueueEntry')
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't read any `.log.*` files and the parser chokes on the files that are read, but are not in xml format. Thanks!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Maybe the [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module can help you:

```
import glob

listing = glob.glob('C:/foo/bar/foo.log*')
for filename in listing:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: If the OP is expecting this to work like wildcards in the Windows `cmd` shell instead of a POSIX shell, it's not quite perfect… but it should be good enough for his use case, and most likely for any use case he's going to come up with, so I think this is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks glob for not expanding `~` - somehow Python makes all the system commands worse than unix...

Comment: Perfect! Though for the path (since it's Windows), I prefer: r"'C:\foo/\bar\foo.log*

Comment: Worth noting you get back a `list`. So if you only expect one file back from `glob` you need to address the list element somehow, e.g. by looping.

Answer (score 17):

> What's the best route to take in order to read and parse only the `foo.log.*` and `foo.log` files? The bar.log files do not need to be read.

Your code does this:

```
if files.endswith('.log'):
```

You've just translated your English description into Python a bit wrong. What you write in Python is: "read and parse only the `*.log` files", meaning `bar.log` is included, and `foo.log.1` is not.

But if you think for a second, you can translate your English description directly into Python:

```
if files == 'foo.log' or files.startswith('foo.log.'):
```

And if you think about it, as long as there are no files named `foo.log.` (with that extra dot) that you want to skip, you can collapse the two cases into one:

```
if files.startswith('foo.log'):
```

However, if you know anything about POSIX shells, `foo.log*` matches exactly the same thing. (That's not true for Windows shells, where wildcards treat extensions specially, which is why you have to type `*.*` instead of `*`.) And Python comes with a module that does POSIX-style wildcards, even on Windows, called `glob`. See stranac's answer for how to use this.

I think the `glob` answer is better than manually filtering `listdir`. It's simpler, it's a more direct match for what your question title says you want to do (just do exactly what you hoped would work with `os.listdir`, but with `glob.glob` instead), and it's more flexible. So, unless you're worried about getting confused by the two slightly different meanings of wildcards, I'd suggest accepting that instead of this one.

Answer (score 9):

This'll give you bash-like regexes:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/tmp/o*"))
```

Alternatively, you could os.listdir the entire directory, and throw away files that don't match a regex via the re module.

Comment: Glob wildcards are not regexes. Well, technically speaking, it is a regular language, but it's not what people think of when they say "regex", and the bash docs explicitly say that it's not regex. `/tmp/o*` does not mean "`/tmp/` followed by 0 or more instances of `o`". See [Globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

Comment: I learned long ago on comp.unix.shell, that *ix has many kinds of regexes, including glob patterns.  The "Advanced Bash Scripting Guide" is not part of the bash documentation - it's a screed written by a perl zealot who probably thinks perl regexes are the only kind of regexes anyone should use.

Comment: Here is [the official POSIX documentation for `glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/glob.html). It doesn't say "regular expression", or anything similar, anywhere. Here is [the official POSIX documentation for `Regular Expressions`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). It specifically defines exactly two languages that count as regular expressions (BRE and ERE). You will find similar wording in the `bash`, `linux`/`glibc`, `*BSD`, etc. documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As several already mentioned: you could use glob.glob to find files using wildcards.
I can't write a comment and it is a very old question, but... Someone suggested, the glob.glob can't expand ~ in the path. So, you can use os.path.expanduser for it, and os.path.expandvars to expand environment variables.